# How to get optionset text in microsoft dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

How do I get the text for an optionset value from a CRM Query?
Here is how I have written my query:

```
function nearByCases(addr){
    var nearByCasesFetchXML = '<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">' +
        '<entity name="incident">' +
          '<attribute name="title"/>' +
          '<attribute name="ticketnumber"/>' +
          '<attribute name="createdon"/>' +
          '<attribute name="new_department"/>' +
          '<attribute name="new_casetype"/>' +
          '<attribute name="incidentid"/>' +
          '<attribute name="caseorigincode"/>' +
          '<order descending="false" attribute="title"/>' +
          '<filter type="and"><condition attribute="new_address" value="'+addr+'" operator="eq"/>' +
          '</filter>' +
        '</entity>' +
      '</fetch>';

    nearByCasesFetchXML = "?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(nearByCasesFetchXML);
    var html = "";
    //var outputText = "Case\t\t\tCreated\n---------------------------------------------------\n";
    window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("incident", nearByCasesFetchXML).then(function success(result) {
      console.log(result.entities);
      if(result.entities.length <=0) {
        window.parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("No results found.", null);
        return false;
      }
      else{
        for (var casecount = 0; casecount < result.entities.length; casecount++) {
         // outputText += result.entities[casecount].ticketnumber+ "\t\t" + result.entities[casecount].title + "\n";
          html += "<tr>";
          html += "<td>"+result.entities[casecount].title+"</td>";
          html += "<td>"+result.entities[casecount].ticketnumber+"</td>";
          html += "<td>"+result.entities[casecount].FormattedValues["new_department"].ToString()+"</td>";
          html += "<td>"+result.entities[casecount].new_casetype+"</td>";
          html += "</tr>";
          $("#nearbycases tbody").html(html);
        }
        return true;
      }
      //window.parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(outputText, null);
    },function (error) {
      // Handle error conditions
      window.parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message, null);
    });

}
```

This is fetchXml to fetch the data from `incident` and I am able to get all incident values but there are some custom optionsets (`new_department`,`new_casetype`) which only return the value, not the text.

So how do I get the text of these option set.

This is the response I get

> ```
> {
>   "@odata.etag": "W/"1999118"" ,
>   "createdon": "2018-12-13T08:30:34Z" ,
>   "createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "12/13/2018 2:30 AM" ,
>   "incidentid": "dedfb05b-b1fe-e811-a977-000d3a33eb4e" ,
>   "new_casetype": 1 ,
>   "new_casetype@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Abandoned Vehicles" ,
>   "new_department": 1 ,
>   "new_department@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Parking Control" ,
>   "ticketnumber": "CAS-01001-H2S7L9" ,
>   "title": "case for sla 1",
> }
> ```

Comment: i am getting the response like this:
@odata.etag: "W/"1999118""
createdon: "2018-12-13T08:30:34Z"
createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue: "12/13/2018 2:30 AM"
incidentid: "dedfb05b-b1fe-e811-a977-000d3a33eb4e"
new_casetype: 1
new_casetype@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue: "Abandoned Vehicles"
new_department: 1
new_department@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue: "Parking Control"
ticketnumber: "CAS-01001-H2S7L9"
title: "case for sla 1"

Answer (score 0):

The `FormattedValue` entries are the text of the option set value.

The response you're getting contains the text so it's just a matter of referencing it.

You can reference them like this:

```
var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
    var departmentCode = results.value[i]["new_department"];
    var departmentCodeText = results.value[i]["new_department@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
}
```

`departmentCode` will be the integer and `departmentCodeText` will be the text.

Rather than what's shown in the question:

```
html +="<td>"+result.entities[casecount].FormattedValues["new_department"].ToString()+"</td>";
```

Try:

```
html += "<td>"+result.entities[casecount]["new_department@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"]+"</td>";
```

Comment: Exactly i am doing like this but i am getting script error like this in console:

CrashReport:
  FileName:
  LineNumber:0
  Function:
  ErrorReport:<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
   <OriginContext>XHRResponse</OriginContext>
   <OriginCorrelationId>5bc3fc46-e99e-4486-a279-03022f55af40</OriginCorrelationId>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Script error.</Message>
   <Line>0</Line>
   <URL></URL>

Comment: @BibhutiBhusanSatpathy upvote/accept the answer to encourage the community volunteers :)